# estimation of distance between means of multivariate gaussian model

Tags: multivariate-analysis, inference, references, multivariate-normal-distribution, order-statistics

Assume that we have a large sample $X_{1}, \dots, X_{n} \in \mathbb{R}^{k}$ from a multivariate normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{\mu}, \bf{I})$. I aim to estimate the smallest distance between the elements of a mean vector $\boldsymbol{\mu} \in \mathbb{R}^{k}$, i.e.
$$
d = \min_{i\neq j}\{|\mu_{j}-\mu_{j}| \text{ s.t. } \mu_{i} \neq \mu_{j}\}.
$$
Note: the elements of vector $\boldsymbol{\mu}$ are not ordered. Also, $k \ll n$ and $k$ does not grow with $n$.

I wonder if this problem has a "name" and solved somewhere? Could bootstrapping help here?

Comment: I don’t think there’s a name for the algorithm, but you can estimate your values via Maximum Likelihood, for example, and then compute the smallest distance among the $\mu_i$ terms.

Comment: Dear @GerardoDuránMartín , I do not agree. In this case you would rather always underestimate the destance. Note: the goal is to estimate the smallest non-zero distance between the components.

Comment: There must be typographical errors in your problem statement, because the quantity doesn't depend on $i$ at all: it is always zero.

Comment: I aim to estimate the smallest distance between non-equal elements of mean-vector. Before, it was written $\text{ s.t. } \mu_{j} \neq \mu_{j}$, which did not make much sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the following solution. One can estimate the number of different components by BIC:
$$
BIC = 2k\log(n) - 2\log(\hat{L}),
$$
which provides strongly consistent model selection. Then, we can estimate $d$ by computing the smallest distance between the estimated constant elements of $\boldsymbol{\mu}$.

Comment: Why is this procedure any good?  At a minimum, you need to analyze the size and distributions of the errors you are likely to make.

Comment: I do not understand... why do I need to specify error? I assume that the sample from Normal distribution, with variance equal to $1$. The simplest possible case. About the size of sample, I assume that it is large enough.